# Собственный шрифт в UINavigationBar

Tags: xcode, ios, ios7

Есть ли более современный способ для установления своего шрифта в UINavigationBar, так чтобы он при этом не обрезался?

```
UIFont* titleFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SomeFont" size:20.0];
CGSize requestedTitleSize = [text sizeWithFont:titleFont];
CGFloat titleWidth = MIN(100, requestedTitleSize.width);

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleWidth, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SomeFont" size:20.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = text;

self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать для этого appearance, вот например общий для некоторых экранов сабкласс UINavigationController:

```
@implementation GTCommonNavigationController

+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:self, nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:131.0/255.0 blue:182.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:self, nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:self, nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                                                                    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:19.0]}];
}

@end
```

можно засетить сразу UI сразу для всех `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:nil];`